# Create custom java annotation in order to modify method

Tags: java, android, annotations

I want to create an annotation in order to make a method asynchronous like @Async in spring but for Android. I checked the annotation processor of java but it does not allow to modify existing class (we can only create new class) I do not want to use the androidannotation library because I also want to learn how to create my own annotations

I saw that lombok allows to modify class (add getter and setter) and we can add custom annotations (https://binkley.blogspot.fr/2014/12/writing-your-own-lombok-annotation.html)

But I have trouble modifying this example to create an asynctask and to inject the code of the method.

Thank you for your help

```
@AsyncTask
void doSomething(int a){
    Log.d("here");
}
```

-->

```
void doSomething(int a){
    new android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground( Void... voids ) {
            Log.d("here");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Modify classes is dangerous and need maintain for every jvm. How about create generated classes or use proxy?

Answer (score 1):

First, we define the annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface AsyncTask {
}
```

Then we use `cglib` to create asyn logic for `@AsyncTask` method:

```
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;

public class AsyncTaskHandler {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T handle(T origin) {
    // collect async methods
    List<Method> asyncMethods = Arrays.stream(origin.getClass().getMethods())
        .filter(m -> m.getAnnotation(AsyncTask.class) != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // if no async method, return itself
    if (asyncMethods.isEmpty()) {
      return origin;
    }
    return (T) Enhancer.create(origin.getClass(), (MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, proxy) -> {
      // if asyn, wrapped in your async code, here I simply create a new thread
      if (asyncMethods.contains(method)) {
        // your async logic
        new Thread(() -> {
          try {
            proxy.invoke(origin, args);
          } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }).start();
        return null;
      }
      return proxy.invoke(origin, args);
    });
  }
}
```

Let's test our code.

```
public class SomeObject {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeObject so = SomeObject.create();
    so.syncDo("1");
    so.asyncDo("2");
    so.syncDo("3");
    so.asyncDo("4");
  }

  public static SomeObject create() {
    return AsyncTaskHandler.handle(new SomeObject());
  }

  protected SomeObject() {}

  @AsyncTask
  public void asyncDo(String who) {
    System.out.println(who + "\tThread: " + Thread.currentThread());
  }

  public void syncDo(String who) {
    System.out.println(who + "\tThread: " + Thread.currentThread());
  }
}
```

and output is:

```
1   Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
3   Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
2   Thread: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
5   Thread: Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you very much for your answer but for performance raisons I wanted annotation with modification of the code during the compilation and not during the runtime. That's why I'm interested in lombok which uses this mechanism.

Comment: @kazouz Lombok modify the AST to generate new bytecode. It's hard to maintain. You would create new class file in annotation processing rather than alter exists code.